# Defining a function that has no return value

Tags: function-construction, return-value

How can I define a function with no return value. For example, the Notation function from the Notation package seems to have no return value; I am looking to do the same thing for some of my custom functions.

Comment: can it not even return `Null`? if you end last line in function with `;` it returns `Null`. And `Null` is like nothing. `seems to have no return value` did you look at the `InputForm` of what it returns? Since `Null` does not print to screen.

Comment: Is that what happens with Notation? I can call Notation[...] without a semicolon and I do not get an Out box. If there is no way to do it without any return value, I can live with that, but it would be cleaner if I could avoid all return values.

Comment: I do not know about using Notation to define functions that is why I asked. But my understanding is that function return last evaluation. So if you put `;` at end you'll get a `Null` as return value. So whatever the last thing in the function is what is returned.  (Unless you have an explicit `Return[..,Module]` in the middle. I do not know how to make a function not even return `Null`. But may be someone knows...

Comment: Ok, just tried it, and Null seems to not produce an Out box, so I think indeed this is what my example of Notation seems to do. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Nasser's response in the comments is correct. Returning Null (using a semicolon in the last statement of the function) gives the behavior I was looking for.